# Disbale block selection with CSS

Tags: css, drupal, menu, selection

I have problem with my theme, my primary menu have some selection border after click in menu area. I tried add some css tricks with selection but problem still exist :( please help me :)

Look for problem & code:
http://i889.photobucket.com/albums/ac91/kazaa8/Przechwytywanie_zpssurksxun.png

```css
   #main-menu.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
visibility: visible;
z-index: 200;
background: #fff;
height: 94px;
width: 100%;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: please provide the code to recreate the problem.

Comment: how the heck are we supposed to know what you're talking about without seeing preferably code? or a link to site?

Comment: any ideas for resolve this problem :( ?

Comment: can't really find a solution with given code, but did you try by adding `outline: none;` ?

Comment: I forgot about outline, work good, thanks for help ! :)